# Suppose $s_n$ is a sequence such that lim $s_n = 5$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

This is a two part problem, and if anyone can help explain them, I would appreciate it.

(a) State the definition of what it means to say that lim $s_n = 5$.

(b) Prove that there exists a real number $N$ such that if $n∈\mathbb{Z}$ and $n>N$, then $s_n<7$.

Comment: You're doing a problem about limits and don't know the definition of a limit? Is it missing from your book?

Comment: @AlexR. I do, but I just like seeing the affirmation of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $\epsilon = 2 \to \exists N$ such that if $n > N \to |s_n-5| < 2 \to s_n-5 < 2 \to s_n < 7$. I hope you can state the def of part $a)$.